# Database Mirroring error, but everything looks OK

Tags: sql-server-2014, mirroring

I'm setting up a Mirroring study session in separated servers.

Everything looks ok, the firewall in my machine is disabled and in the another server it has an inbound\outbound rule to accept port 5022.

I could check that both endpoints are created and STARTED in both servers
with `SELECT * FROM sys.database_mirroring_endpoints`.

[image]

I tried with both configurations, by using services account, and leaving them blank.

I checked with `port query` that the server is listening on this ports:

[image]

What more can I check?

[image]

The reason I'm asking this question is because I read every other question about mirroring here, but none of them could help me.

---

In a post, I read that someone fixed the error with:

> Go to services.msc and check the sql server is running under which
>   account. Make sure that sql server and sql server agent services
>   should run with same credentials.

But I use different credentials for AGENT and SQL SERVER.

Is this a problem? I've never seen this before.

---

EDIT2:

I could fix this error ( it still shows me this error, but if I run the mirror again, it shows me error `1431`.)

Using `ALTER DATABASE [Database_Name] SET PARTNER OFF` didn't solve the problem. it just restart the task, and errors and errors again.

Comment: Are they both the same edition of SQL?

Comment: Yes, both SQL Server 2014.

Comment: That's version.  What edition(s)?  Such as Developer, Enterprise, or Standard.

Comment: Oh Sorry, both enterprise edition.

Comment: Are both instances of sql server running under the same service account? If not you'll need to use a certificate and proxy accounts.

Comment: Yes I just check this. both are using the same service account.

Comment: and its not networkservice. its a domain account.

Comment: Did you go through the configure security wizard which sets the endpoint security ? What does the errorlog say on both the servers

Answer (score 1):

Have you granted the CONNECT permission to the Mirroring Endpoint for the SQL Server service account?

GRANT CONNECT on ENDPOINT::Mirroring_Endpoint TO [domain\user];